# Git local changes / diff / JGIT

Tags: java, git, git-diff, jgit, git-status

I'm stuck at the following problem:

This is what I want:

- a git command, that I can use to show the 'US' changes
- it should work like status, (show what I did) in comparisation to the remote

This is what I tried:

1. git diff [in JGit -> diffentry] with many options e.G. master..branchName
2. I tried to find a git status cmd, that does work with 2 commits.
3. I watched through the whole diffEntry[JGIT] methods to find a method to get my desired Output
4. I googled for JGit methods, that will show me my desired Output

   To 1. -> **The problem is** : When I change a file on remote, the git diff command shows the file as 'M' for modified, but the user did not modified it, it may be true, but is not what I search

   To 2. -> git Status is something I'd like to use, because it shows exactly what I want.... but only from index to head...

**For what?**

I want a list from all files that the User had modified/added/deleted so I can iterate through it and put head informations in every file, just before he pushes the file.

**Hows the workflow?**

I clone a branch, do N-commits and now I want to push.
Every file in this N-commits must be modified. (and that's the Problem with this modified, if it's modified in the remote branch, but not locally, than I should not touch it with my script, but I have no way to differentiate between this two)

€dit: Additional Infos

git diff-index  does nearly what I want.
The problem: I need to filter only 'our' changes. So if a file is modified on remote, I dont want to see it. I want to see MY modified files.

Comment: Indulge me if you will.  Are you just looking for a way to see the differences between your local changes and the remote?

Comment: Yes, but with the following restriction:

git diff shows a file as Modified if it was modified on the remote branch, but I want to show the User only the files HE modified/deleted/added, so it's confusing, if he sees a modified file, that he had not touched.

Comment: I am not 100% clear in what you are asking but here are some suggestions.  git diff origin/master will give you the diffs between your local branch and the remote.  You can also do: git fetch origin if you know there are changes on the remote, and to see the differences you do git log -p HEAD..origin.  Another possibility to find differences is $ git diff --name-status master..branchName (obviously changing the names relevant branch names).  I've got a feeling the last one might be what you are looking for?

Comment: The Problem with those calls is, they do not differentiate.

Especially the last one is NEARLY what I want.
It shows my current modificated files. But now the Problem: It shows me a file as modified, if I have not modified it, but it was modified on remote, and there is no way I can see which side modified it.

I want to see user changes ONLY (modified, deleted, added).

Comment: did you try git diff-index <branch name>, it should compare only against the index so not the remote; you can also look at git diff-files

Comment: git diff-index does the same.
A file is marked as modified, even if the local branch did not modify it. (It is correct from git side, but not what I want, I want to see only my own modify)
diff-files is only shows to the last commit. But thanks!

I looked at the help page for the diff-index and what I need is a Filter to show only MY side of Modify/delete/add - is this possible?

Comment: but if you do git fetch before doing the diff, you should have only your change

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see changes on Your side only, you should update the index before you diff, so run `git fetch <remote> <branch>` and your index tree will be up to date, after this you can run `git diff-index <branch>`

you can add the `--diff-filter=ADM` if you want to select only files that are Added (A), Deleted (D), Modified (M)

Comment: I just tested it and it does not work:
Heres what I've done:
-OTHER PC-
(on another PC than mine) //
1) git clone
2) git checkout develop
3) file modify
4) git commit -a -m "test"
5) git push
-MY PC-
(on my pc, current branch master) //
1)git fetch origin develop
2)git diff-index --name-status origin/develop

And the modified file from the other pc is shown..
I guess I do something wrong
Thanks for your help so far

Comment: once you fetch origin, just diff against the local index `git diff-index --name-status`

Comment: If I write this command exactly like this, I'll get an info text on how to use the command.

Maybe it's because we use git 2.6?